# Woocommerce list products in a category matching an attribute

Tags: wordpress, attributes, woocommerce, categories, product

How do I list the products in a category that match an attribute? Preferably using shortcodes but any method including php would be good.

So far I have tried [product_category category="dogs"] which lists all products in the category dogs regardless of attributes.

Then I tried [product_attribute attribute='colour' filter='brown'] but that lists all products that are brown from all categories which means it shows brown cats as well as dogs.

I want to list all "brown dogs" where dogs is the category and brown is an attribute. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Visit this 2 links which very related to your question bro ..

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123993/shortcode-not-working
http://oik-plugins.eu/woocommerce-a2z/oik_api/wc_shortcodesproduct_attribute/

Comment: Thanks. The first of those links looks like a different question and the second does not appear to list products matching category + product attribute. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

[product_attribute attribute="kplichestvo_etagey" filter="odnoetagniy"  category="bani_s_basseinom"]

Comment: Please provide more details about how did you get this answer? How this is going to solve the problem and where should we put this?